# Dropbox Filename search is not returning files end with tar.gz

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've a dropbox folder where there files with a pattern; `files_<date>.targ.gz`

Example:

```
Folder: /Data
files_20151103.tar.gz
files_20151102.tar.gz
....
```

When I search for `20151103` in `/Data` folder I'm not getting any files back.  Does dropbox ignores files with extension `tar.gz`?

Here is my python code

```
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('TOKEN')
dbx.files_search('/Data', '20151103')
SearchResult(matches=[], more=False, start=0)
```

I tried even on dropbox website searching for 20151103 didn't give any results.

This was working till two day ago.  Any changes happen in search over last two days?

Is there any workaround for this?  My code is failing for last two days as it's not able to search files in dropbox.

It appears that `files_search` is not returning any file older than 2 days.  Is it a limitation of search?

Comment: You mention `tar.gz` but your files seem to only have the `.gz` suffix. I'd be surprised if it was ignoring gz files.

Comment: That was mistake.  I modified the original post.

Comment: Are you sure the search method is _find this string anywhere in the file name_? What if it's looking for files that _begin with_ your query?'

Comment: This works fine for me using your exact file names/structure/code. Are you sure you're connected to the right account? Try `dbx.files_list_folder("/Data")` to check the file listing.

Comment: I'm doing this search on dropbox website also.  Same behavior can't get the files.  

When I do dbx.files_list_folder('/Data') I do get the files that end with .tar.gz .  It's just search is not returning.

Does search has a time limit on which days it goes back for search?  These files are two day old.

Comment: There's no limit like that. It sounds like this may be specific to your account then. Please open a ticket if you haven't already: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: Observing same behavior for any file which are older than 2 days.  Basically files_search is not returning any file which are older.  Same thing happening with dropbox website also.

FYI: This is a shared folder.  would it be a restriction on shared folder?

Comment: It looks like this may be a bug searching for older files. We're looking into it.

Comment: This should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes it's fixed.  Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed now.  There was some issue on dropbox side and they fixed it.